# Major.minor unsupported version 51.0 Java MAC OSX

Tags: java, macos

Ok if i try run a java file from console i get unsupported major.minor 51.0. These class files were't compiled on my MAC osx. BUT... If I'm in finder and right click the class file and open with jar launcher it loads. Im trying to load it with terminal, java programName. My java version in console says
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

BUT in sys-pref-java it says Platform: 1.7  product: 1.7.0_51

Terminal using a different version? Not sure what to do.

Comment: Could be a PATHk issue

Answer (score 2):

You should set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the results of the `/usr/libexec/java_home` command (which evaluates to your system configured Java version).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)"
```